# what does it means to have a linear system Ax=b, where rank A =n-1?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

let $ Ax=b $ be a system of linear equations where $ A $ is an $ n \times n $ matrix with $ rank (A )= n-1 $, the system has infinitely many solutions, I want to now the difference between when the $ rank( A) = n-1 $ and for example if we have $ rank( A) = n-2 $, $ rank (A) = 4 $,....
I'm asking about the difficulty level? I dont understand why $ rank( A) = n-1 $ is it important?
I hope someone can explain this to me, thank you.

Comment: I’m not sure what “difference” you’re looking for, but are you familiar with the rank-nullity theorem?

Comment: As alluded to by Joe, the nullity of the matrix $A$ is the dimension of the subspace of vectors who get mapped to the zero vector and the nullity will always add to the rank to total $n$... so with the rank being $n-1$ that means the nullity will be $1$ and with rank being $n-3$ the nullity will be $3$ and so on.  With a nullity of $3$ for instance that means that if we had a particular solution for $x$ to the equation, what I'll label $p$ (*p for* '**p**'*articular*) $Ap=b$, and if $n_1,n_2,n_3$ were basis vectors of the nulspace then $\alpha_1n_1+\alpha_2n_2+\alpha_3n_3+p$ is also a solution

Comment: This, for any values of $\alpha_1,\dots$ since we would have $A(\alpha_1n_1+\alpha_2n_2+\alpha_3n_3+p)=\alpha_1 A(n_1)+\dots+\alpha_3 A(n_3)+Ap = 0+0+0+b=b$.  Yes, its infinitely many solutions, just like in the rank(A)=n-1 case, but here we have a "larger dimension" number of solutions.  See also [Affine space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_space).

Comment: Note that $Ax = b$ need not have infinitely many solutions. What you know is that: _if_ $Ax = b$ has one solution, _then_ $Ax = b$ has infinitely many solutions. However, $\operatorname{rank}A = n - 1$ actually implies that there's a $b \in \Bbb R^{n \times 1}$ such that $Ax = b$ has **no** solution.

Comment: Thank you  for your responses, Aryaman Maithani can you please explain more.